# Many-one Reducibility Understanding Problem

Tags: logic, computability

We know for every set $B$, that be r.e have:

$$B\leq_mK$$

(The set $B$ is many-one reducible, or m-reducible, to the set $K$)

we know $K$ is r.e and define:

$$K=\{ e:e\in W_e\}$$

my challenge is:

> if A is a r.e Set why the following is true?
>   $$\overline K\leq_m \overline A$$
>   $$\overline A\leq_m\overline K$$

Comment: Don't add back irrelevant tags. Computational complexity is more nuanced that whether a set is r.e. or not. The study of reducibilities should not be about Turing machines and their specifics. If you still need to think about these reductions in terms of Turing machines, it is reasonable to assume you are still not ready to actually think about these questions. Similarly, there is nothing about first-order logic in this question. Adding irrelevant tags is just not helpful. (Also, all these questions are quite basic, you may want to show some effort rather than keep asking so many of them.)

Comment: I've also changed the title, as the question is not really about Turing reducibility. The way you state the problem makes no sense. You shouldn't say that "we know $K$ is r.e. and define ..." First you have to define the set, before you can "know" anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a recursively enumerable set, it is not true that $\bar{K} \leq_m \bar{A}$. For instance if $A = \emptyset$, which is a recursive set (and hence recursively enumerable). If your claim was true, then

$\bar{K} \leq_m \bar{\emptyset} = \omega$.

This would imply that $\bar{K}$ is computable. Then $K$ is computable, which it is not.

Comment: To be explicit, it is not *generally* true. Of course $\bar{K}\leq_m \bar{K}$.